# Money transfer as a loan for educational purpose

Tags: united-states, taxes, student-loan, private-lending

I live in the US. A friend in another country (Caribbeans) is in need of cash $15000 for educational purposes. How would one transfer money properly? I suppose it is possible for me to transfer the cash as tuition fees directly to the university (a legitimate one). If done so, this friend would like to return the money back to me in an year or so. How would he actually go about doing it?   Any advice or share your experience if any?

Comment: which countries?

Comment: Just a bit of quick advice: Friends + Loans don't mix well. If you expect to be fully repaid, make sure everything is in writing and a legally binding contract. Otherwise, make sure you're comfortable with the possibility of never seeing that money again. You're a good friend, but just be sure to protect yourself.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I updated the question with the countries. The university is in the Caribbeans

Comment: @BobbyScon True. I will eventually have to get this done with legal advixe

Comment: There are 13 independent countries and 4 countries that have territories/protectorates there. "Caribbeans" is not specific enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can wire the money to the university. If your friend is a registered student, then they will have an account at the school.

Contact the school directly and ask for the "bursar's office" (assuming it is an English speaking school). The bursar will tell you how to wire the money so that it reaches the proper account. Normally, you will wire to a general university account at a bank and the memo on the wire will include the student's account number.

Your friend can wire money to your account at your bank. Go to your bank and ask them for the procedure.

By the way, there is a 90% chance your "friend" will not pay you back.